# Payments Lookup EXCEL - What function to insert when blank if it changes by week

Tags: microsoft-excel-2013, lookup

In excel, I need to show on a "summary" tab the payments that should be made Friday by Friday. I have this information on another tab, where you can find a list of names of whom we should pay and right next a table the amount we should pay each person week by week. (not all the people are paid weekly). I need to display:

1. the total amount I should pay each Friday (I know how to do this)
2. A list that appears as I input a date on the "summary" tab which shows whom should I pay to that Friday, and how much should I pay each person. This should change as I change the date. 
   -I've tried to do a lookup with a IF function.

Comment: I understand what you want. I suggest you have a go yourself. I have no idea what you've tried. And we're not here to do your work for you. As such I'm voting to close. However, please do edit your question to show us what youv'e tried and I can remove my close vote :)

Comment: "I've tried to do a lookup with a IF function." - that still doesn't clarify your problem:(. Please add some sample data, with desired output, and also the formula you've tried (with description where exactly it failed).